# Is there a way to declare postgresql row immutable given a condition?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm creating records in a transaction.

```
begin;
update parent_records where id=5 set closed = now();
insert into child_records ...;
commit;
```

I want to prevent inserting new child_records once the parent record is `closed`. It seems like setting a rule on parent_records to blow up on `update` actions when closed would solve the problem, as the transaction would fail.

I could do the update with `where closed is null` then check in app code if any rows were updated and rollback, but i would rather the constraint be in the database itself.

How do i mark the parent row immutable (updates fail with error) when a condition is met (`closed` column not null)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a trigger, e.g.:

```
create function before_update_on_parent_records()
returns trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
    if old.closed is not null then
        raise exception 'cannot update because the row is closed';
    end if;
    return new;
end $$;

create trigger before_update_on_parent_records
before update on parent_records
for each row execute procedure before_update_on_parent_records();
```

Comment: it says `unterminated dollar-quoted string at or near "$$`